# Why does my database stop getting updated when I try to convert string to decimal?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Why does mySQl database stop getting updated when I try to convert a column to double? Normally my android app sends the gps location to my database every 2 seconds and it works perfectly but the data being transmitted is of string type I need to convert the string to double/decimal for distance calculations which I can do successfully using CAST() but upon doing so the database stops getting updated with the new values being transmitted from the app. 
Here is my code to connect and send data to my database.

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect(localhost, 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('finalyearproject');
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$Number=$_POST['Number'];
$Latitude=$_POST['Lat'];
$Longitude=$_POST['Long'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO app_backup(Number,Latitude, Longitude) VALUES('$Number', '$Latitude', '$Longitude') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Latitude=VALUES(Latitude), Longitude=VALUES(Longitude)";
$sql ="UPDATE app_backup SET Latitude=CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(10,6)), Longitude = CAST(Longitude AS DECIMAL(10,6))";

$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not enter data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Entered data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

the code works perfectly without

```
$sql ="UPDATE app_backup SET Latitude=CAST(Latitude AS DECIMAL(10,6)), Longitude = CAST(Longitude AS DECIMAL(10,6))";
```

I assumed it stops updating because the data im sending is string and the column is converted to decimal, therefore I made another column to keep the the decimal converted values and not convert the original column, yet I faced the same error.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions, use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: Why you want to update query?, when it is working perfectly.